# CSS: Having a weird issue on an image when deployed to mobile/iPhones

Tags: css, iphone

When I use Chrome's dev tools to emulate the screen size and resolution, it all seems fine and looks fine, however when deployed the image sometimes comes back as being squashed on the height attribute like so:

[image: Picture Example]

Is there something I am missing in the CSS for this or is it a weird iOS quirk that I've not accounted for?

HTML

```
 <div class="header-image">
        <img class="profileImg" src="{{coachImageBasePath + coachDetails.imageUrl}}" alt="Coach Image"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.profileImg{
  float: none;
  margin: 0;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  min-width: auto;
  max-width: 400px;
  min-height: auto;
  max-height: max-content
}

@media (max-width: 450px) {
  .profileImg{
    height: 180px;
    width: 180px;
  }
```

Whats weird is this is working on a varity of Android devices, just iPhone 11 and 12 that is not working

Comment: Could you please share your HTML and CSS of the implementation?
I guess that you set the image width to `100%` and height to `auto` which removes the aspect ratio of the initial image

Comment: added to the main post

Comment: Please make your code into a runnable snippet and check that it really does show the problem - include a typical image. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with adding a snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `Width: 100%` and the `Height: auto` attrbutes fixed this issue